# How much this site is/ going to be on-topic to bio student lacking a proper IT and stat base?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, scope

I felt like if anyone have to learn bioinformatics in the 'proper' way, conceptually; then a base of statistics, data-modelling and computer-programing is a prerequisite. But biology students of most traditional courses; often completely  lack that  basis (such as me is one), and also, bioinformatics is taught directly on masters or equivalent grade (or maybe a little bit introduction in college or bachelor's' grade).

So, how much on topic this site is/ going to be, for such typical bio students who might ask very basic questions about bioinformatics (not expert-like one)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think that there would be any problem asking very basic questions, so long as they are asked in a way that follows the site guidelines.  StackOverflow is full of 'Hello World' questions, and there is nothing wrong with that, so long as the questions are not duplicated.  Once this site has matured, it should hopefully be able to cover even the most basic of bioinformatics questions.  It will be up to users to search for existing questions before posting, though, so as not to pollute the site with the same questions over and over.

Comment: While I totally agree with this response, I would like to add that during the private beta period we are encouraged to enrich the site with expert-level question. This probably means avoiding very basic questions until the next phase.

Comment: I wonder if this site might always be slightly "higher level" than biostars. Biostars is explicitly for helping beginners. I feel like binfo SE should not be hostile to beginners or non-experts, but would definitely aim at being less handhold-y.